# how to setup send-only email server on ubuntu

Tags: server, email, postfix, smtp

I have a project coming soon and I need to send an email to around 300K people who might have the interest in the project. However I need to send them an email in the same day (the opening day) and as you know most of the web hosting companies won't let me send that amount of emails in the same day. So, I want to setup the email server at home and I'll code a script to send the emails in row so I don't push the server too far.

How can I setup my own email server on Ubuntu at home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you get your list of 300K addresses? If you did it correctly, there are certainly companies who will let you do this. Did you have people sign up to be on this list? If so, then a lot of hosting companies would be fine with you sending lots of mail out to reach everyone on your list. Mailchimp is one that comes to mind.

Additionally, most network operators/ISP block outgoing email that doesn't go through their server, so your plan may not work even if you get the server set right.

In addition, most ISPs will filter into the spam box any messages delivered directly from customer address space -- if they don't just straight up refuse the message when you try to hand it off. The same goes for dynamic address space (most end user connections are this) and IP addresses that don't have a non-numeric reverse DNS entry (so not things like 96-39-177.someisp.net). If you tell me what your address is, I can take a look and give you an idea of if messages from it would be accepted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I really don't want to jump to any conclusion without trying to send the emails. I can pay some extra money to have a static IP address and setup the other needed services, but I want to know where to start, and about the list I got them from some companies in my country that has the almost the same interest.

Comment: If you go to a site like ipchicken.com and give me the address that it gives there I can look on some mail server tools I have and tell you whether it was pass the checks.

Comment: I think I'm going to consult one of my professors , Thanks anyway